# Using multiple temporary tables in a single MySQL query (works in phpMyAdmin, but not PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I would like to avoid using real tables as a work-around. I am trying to join two tables and get unique values for the column I'm calling `unique_values_needed`, while also prioritizing the value 11 when it is present in duplicate `real_secondary_table_primary_key`.

Here is the code (it works in phpMyAdmin, but not in PHP):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temporary_table_1
    AS (SELECT real_main_table.*, 
               real_secondary_table.real_secondary_table_primary_key 
          FROM real_main_table
               LEFT JOIN real_secondary_table 
                         ON real_secondary_table.real_main_table_primary_key = real_main_table.real_main_table_primary_key
      ORDER BY real_main_table.date DESC);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temporary_table_2
    AS (SELECT real_main_table.*, 
               real_secondary_table.real_secondary_table_primary_key 
          FROM real_main_table
               LEFT JOIN real_secondary_table 
                         ON real_secondary_table.real_main_table_primary_key = real_main_table.real_main_table_primary_key
      ORDER BY real_main_table.date DESC);

UPDATE temporary_table_1 t1, temporary_table_2 t2
   SET t1.real_secondary_table_primary_key = t2.real_secondary_table_primary_key
 WHERE     t1.real_main_table_primary_key = t2.real_main_table_primary_key 
       AND t1.real_secondary_table_primary_key  11 
       AND t2.real_secondary_table_primary_key = 11;

  SELECT * 
    FROM temporary_table_1 
GROUP BY unique_values_needed
ORDER BY temporary_table_1.date DESC;
```

I have also tried the following (again, it works in phpMyAdmin, but still not in PHP):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temporary_table_1
    AS (SELECT real_main_table.*, 
               real_secondary_table.real_secondary_table_primary_key 
          FROM real_main_table
               LEFT JOIN real_secondary_table 
                         ON real_secondary_table.real_main_table_primary_key = real_main_table.real_main_table_primary_key
      ORDER BY real_main_table.date DESC);

UPDATE temporary_table_1 t1, (
       SELECT real_main_table.*, 
              real_secondary_table.real_secondary_table_primary_key 
         FROM real_main_table
              LEFT JOIN real_secondary_table 
                        ON real_secondary_table.real_main_table_primary_key = real_main_table.real_main_table_primary_key
     ORDER BY real_main_table.date DESC) t2
   SET t1.real_secondary_table_primary_key = t2.real_secondary_table_primary_key
 WHERE     t1.real_main_table_primary_key = t2.real_main_table_primary_key 
       AND t1.real_secondary_table_primary_key  11 
       AND t2.real_secondary_table_primary_key = 11;

  SELECT * 
    FROM temporary_table_1 
GROUP BY unique_values_needed
ORDER BY temporary_table_1.date DESC;
```

When I checked using `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())`, the error is supposedly either when creating the second temporary table (in the first code example), or in the `UPDATE` when using `(SELECT ...) t2` (in the second code example).

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE real_main_table;`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE real_secondary_table;` and desired output. Also [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I'm confused--doesn't that just output the SQL needed to make the tables? Do you want me to post the tables here? EDIT: Nevermind, I see your question's been clarified.

Comment: Are you sure you use the same connection (session) to the db from php side ? also post the error you receive

Comment: `mysql_query` is supposed to execute only one statement. You should be using [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) , sorry I don't know a mysql_* equivalent.

Comment: Deprecated: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO

Comment: It won't let me edit the question any more--someone else edited it and now when I try it tells me that I have code that is not properly formatted. The error from `mysql_error()` is simply a syntax error in the locations I specified.

Comment: Also, is there any way of doing this while continuing to use `mysql_query`? I can't go through all the code and change everything to `mysqli_*`. Alternatively, is using both a problem? (i.e. not removing the `mysql_connect`, while also adding `mysqli_connect`?)

Comment: @user3191820 check my comment. you cannot execute multiple queries with `mysql_query()` so you are getting error on the second query part. on both cases. using both in the same code is not a problem but you cannot mix them like open with `mysql_open()` and query with `mysqli_query()` and vice versa.

Comment: @bansi Yes, I saw and threw you another question. It seems that `mysql_*` does not have a `mysqli_multi_query` equivalent though. I'll accept this as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute multiple queries with `mysql_query()` You should use [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to do this. There is no equivalent of `mysqli_multi_query` in `mysql_*` functions.

You can use both `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` in the same code but be careful not to mix them up like open with mysql_open() and query with mysqli_query() and vice versa. Once the connection is opened with `mysqli_open()` you should use only `mysqli_*` functions on that connection. This applies for `mysql_*` connection also. But you  can have both connections open at the same time from the same code.

**Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.